# SpringBoot, Thymeleaf

Tags: html, thymeleaf

Can somebody explain me what's going on? 
I'm using  thymeleaf and springboot
i got template file

out.html

```html
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http:www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SAD</title>
    <link th:href="@{/css/style.css}" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<h1>sad</h1>

<div class="container">
    <div th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(list)}">
        <h2>People to deport</h2>
        <table class ="table table-striped">

            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Surname</th>
                <th width="100px">Age</th>
            </tr>

            <tr th:each = "people :${list}">
                <td  th:text="${people.name}"></td>
                <td  th:text="${people.surname}"></td>
                <td  th:text="${people.age}"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<p th:text="#{hello}">text</p>


</body>
</html>
```

I got request mapping on it in my controller. It works correctly. But as you see i used resource bundle and my default language is russian.  (it has displayed '?' signs) on that place.

```html
<p th:text="#{hello}">text</p>
```

So i wanted to display russian language content on my page . I changed charset from UTF-8 to UTF-16 and everything crashed. Actually codding type is not matter cause  i tried to do that with charset=ISO-8859-1

Server starts, displays other templates. But that one does not work even if i turn back UTF-8 charset back and restart server.

I solved it like:
1. I copied my html from it;
2.Delete the file and create new  named also out.html; 
3.Put that html in the file and it works.

So can somebody explain what is going on?